# My hair doesn't flap in the wind

Tags: particles, physics, hair, force-fields

I have a logo consisting of two letters covered in fur that I am trying to get blowing in the wind for a client project. I have a wind force field on which is affecting the hair fine, but the hair doesn't flap, it just drifts in the wind direction and stays still.

I'm sure I'm relatively new to Blender so I'm sure I'm just doing something wrong. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want to add a "turbulence" force field as well.

Comment: That worked! I'd of assumed that wind would have had its own turbulence. I'm sure there's some clever reason for it!

Much appreciated

Comment: Glad it worked. I think the difference is that a wind modifier on its own will blow smoke like it does off a smokestack - smooth and flowing - whereas adding a turbulence modifier gives smoke like off a camp fire - fluffy and chaotic.